# Wrap Text in openPD

Tags: openpdf

Is there a way to wrap text around an image in openPDF? or around other text? I'm trying to mesh two texts onto one page (texts which may contain pictures), but one text may be larger or smaller then the other. They could look like one of these two pictures:

[image: text one is larger]
[image: text two is larger]

I was going to make a column text, and test the length of text 2 against the length of the text of text 1 that remains after the first few lines (see the picture), but I couldn't return the remaining text with columnText.go(true).

Is there an easy way to wrap text around a picture or other variable object (aka text)?